# securely authenticate client to server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, authentication

System specs:
C# client using .NET 3.0. WCF services hosted as windows services on App Servers. MSSql Server 2008R2 DB for data storage.

Hashes of user passwords are stored in the DB for authenticating users. My problem is, I do not know how to securely authenticate the client to the server, using the hash of the client's password.

Having read similar questions on SO, I saw that a challenge-response mechanism was recommended. Could some one give any good coding examples of how this can be done?

Also, if we can securely generate private-public key pair on the server and distribute the public key to all the clients, would using a public key encryption for passing information from the client and server suffice instead of using challenge-response.

EDIT: By Client I meant the user who will be actually using the client machine for logging in.

Comment: By client do you mean the user using the client or the client application itself. Also are in all windows environment, i.e. clients are on same AD domain as service and are you using net.tcp or http transport.

Comment: @user428468: You already have the authentication scheme in place correct? And are looking for a way to secure the communication during authentication?

Comment: @Pratik: They are not doing any sort of Windows credentials authentication: "Hashes of user passwords are stored in the DB for authenticating users."

Comment: Yes, the authentication scheme is already in place (password hashes and random salts), but we need secure the communication between the client and server. Also, we are using net.tcp for transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you client and server are on same AD domain the simplest option is to use net.tcp transport with AD authentication. The user kerberos token is presented to the service and can be authenticated using AD roles.
If you cannot use integrated AD authentication and have to use the scheme you can use a custom username [validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use SSL for your client-server communication and your public key (AKA asymmetric) encryption is taken care of. You don't need to code it yourself [just configure it to use SSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: SSL doesn't provide any authentication mechanism for clients as asked. It is possible using client certificates but I will not recommend it if you have many users, specially as the WCF service is hosted not in IIS but windows service, client certs are not trivial to set up.

Comment: @Pratik: That's right, SSL only secures the communications. The OP's question (i think) is asking how do you secure their existing authentication method. The following statement proves that they are already doing custom auth: 'Hashes of user passwords are stored in the DB for authenticating users' and they are probably just looking to secure it.

Answer (score 0):

The process would look like this :-

Server generates a challenge and sends to client. e.g. X

At Client

passwordHashed = Hash(password)
challengeHashClient   = Encrypt(X, passwordHashed) //passwordHashed is the key

send challengeHashClient to server.

At the server

get passwordhashed from database
challengeHashServer = Encrypt(X, passwordhashed)

Match challengeHashServer  with challengeHashClient

Also there has to be a timeout for this operation to prevent replay attack.

However if you are using Windows Environment why not think of using Windows Kerberos Authentication ?